# GegenbauerC function, from MATHEMATICA to Python

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica

I have a question regarding to the GegenbauerC function in MATHEMATICA. We can use GegenbauerC[n,a,x] to get the specific value in MATHEMATICA, say:

GegenbauerC[2,-0.5,0.1] = 0.495
However, I need to use the same GegenbauerC function in Python and I found an option of scipy.special.gegenbauer(n,a), but somehow the value of the parameter "a" in Python needs to be greater than -0.5, how this constraint can be "removed" in order to make it performs the same as it does in MATHEMATICA?
Many thanks!

Comment: You might just pass -0.5 + ulp?    (I can't fathom why you'd want \alpha=-0.5 however.)